# Regular Expression to Validate if it is not a Decimal or Integer Number

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression to find out the number which is not entered as proper decimal or integer number in a input box

Examples

1. 1..  - Catch         // consecutive Repeating dots
2. ABC  - Catch         // All Alphabets
3. 1.1.1- Catch         // dots repeating in a number
4. !,@,#- Catch         // All Special Characters

My current below allow me to catch all examples except example -3 where decimal dots can be repeated in any combination.

```cs
void T1_HTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(T1_H.Text, "[^0-9.-]+|[.]{2}"))            
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
        T1_H.Text="";
    }
}
```

Comment: you could, instead, use try{ Convert.ToInt32(input);}catch(Exception){// not int}. If yiu really want to valid using regex, then try: -?[0-9]+(.[0.9]+)? to check is the input is a number.

Comment: P.S.: You can negate the regex to check if the input is not a number... obviously

Comment: Try this regex: `^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$`. Working example: https://regex101.com/r/iRaRPX/1/. It will check for all integers and decimal numbers upto two decimal points. You can change that according to your req.

Comment: `int.TryParse` and `decimal.TryParse` are better options than regex.

Comment: Also you can use NumericUpDown instead of TextBox.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. –

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a regexp you can use: `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$`.

You can test it here https://regex101.com/r/UB6eRT/1

If you want to know if it's a valid number you can also try to convert it and check if you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

**Explanation**:

- ^ asserts position at start of a line
- Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]+
- **+** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
  giving back as needed (greedy)
  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- 1st Capturing Group ([.][0-9]{1,2})?
- **?** Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Match a single character present in the list below [.]
  . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{1,2}
  {1,2} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- $ asserts position at the end of a line

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/iRaRPX/1/

It will check for all integers and decimal numbers up to two decimal points. You can change that according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this with Regular expression, you can use.

```
^(\d*\.)?\d+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BIEKwN/1/)

But please be aware that you can use `Decimal.TryParse` as well. You can read more on Decimal.TryParse [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)